# pystache: render context inside lambda

Tags: python, mustache

This is very similar to https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/issues/157, however in the mentioned post didn't really answer...

My target: print the following lines:

```
Al,John,Jack
Tim,Tom,Todd
```

**without** a final comma.

I tried this way:

```
ctx = {
    'gangs': [
        {'gangsters': [ {'name': 'Al' }, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Jack'}]},
        {'gangsters': [ {'name': 'Tim'}, {'name': 'Tom'} , {'name': 'Todd'}]},
    ]
}


class Lambdas(object):
    def __init__(self, renderer):
        self.renderer = renderer

    def rstrip(self):
        "Remove last character"
        print self.renderer.context
        return lambda s: self.renderer.render(s, self.renderer.context)[:-1]

renderer = pystache.Renderer(missing_tags='strict')

print renderer.render("""
    {{#gangs}}
        {{#rstrip}}{{#gangsters}}{{name}},{{/gangsters}}{{/rstrip}}
    {{/gangs}}
""", ctx, Lambdas(renderer))
```

The output:

```
ContextStack({'gangs': [{'gangsters': [{'name': 'Al'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Jack'}]}, {'gangsters': [{'name': 'Tim'}, {'name': 'Tom'}, {'name': 'Todd'}]}]}, <__main__.Lambdas object at 0x15cadb10>, {'gangsters': [{'name': 'Al'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Jack'}]})
ContextStack({'gangs': [{'gangsters': [{'name': 'Al'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Jack'}]}, {'gangsters': [{'name': 'Tim'}, {'name': 'Tom'}, {'name': 'Todd'}]}]}, <__main__.Lambdas object at 0x15cadb10>, {'gangsters': [{'name': 'Al'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Jack'}]})

Al,John,Jack
Al,John,Jack
```

The culprit is the invocation to render() inside rstrip. Notice how, during the second call, the 3d element of the ContextStack is exactly identical to the previous call.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something?!?

Answer (score 2):

Answered upstream: https://github.com/defunkt/pystache/issues/158

```
def rstrip(self):
    "Remove last character"
    return lambda s: copy.deepcopy(self.renderer).render(s, self.renderer.context)[:-1]
```

Comment: This issue had me bashing my head against the desk all morning XD thanks for sharing the answer ;)